# Prevent multiple users from editing the same item

Tags: safecracker, users, editor

Working on a site with several steps that have to be done by different editors. I am afraid of data loss through cross-editing (two or more users editing an entry at the same time).

The item should not be locked down completely, I would just like to have a warning displayed. This would prevent accidental lockdown (someone leaves their browser open while editing a post and goes to lunch).

This all has to happen on a Safecracker form.

There is one add-on on devotee, but the reviews say that it breaks Zoo Admin and the author seems to be unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Publisher](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) or [Publisher Lite](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher-lite) by Brian Litzinger. I have been using Publisher since the beta release without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Edit Alarm in the past with pretty good results. I didn't use it with Zoo Admin, so I'm not sure if this is the same add-on you're referring to, but it's free and will likely do what you need with very little footprint. If you want more advanced features, I would also go with Justin's recommendation of Publisher.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/edit-alarm

Comment: Does this work with safecracker? I can only find info for the Wiki module.

Comment: This is strictly a Control Panel/Publish Page only add-on. I don't believe it will work with safecracker.